# Economic Model: Incentive Compatible Market Economy that Satisfies Basic Needs

Tags: markets, social-welfare, communism, basic-income

The capitalism system relies on a monetary system for exchange of goods and services. This appears to cause a large number of problems. For example, we shun those that don't have money.

Is there an economic model that embodies and *actually* encourages hard work while discouraging laziness **and** at the same time makes sure that everyone has what they need to live, to survive? Is there a model that marries the best of the other economic models into one that promotes motivation and community unity?

A model where your basic needs are cared for. Food, clothing, housing, education, and medicine is available to everyone. Yet everyone strives for more in their lives. There isn't a massive amount of laziness and instead people live for the things that make them happy and benefit society.

What would that entail? How would I embody such things into one model? Is it even possible?

Comment: It's called Scandinavia. You should visit some time :)

Comment: It's probably a good rule of thumb that any post with more than, say, four occurrences of first person pronouns is off topic.

Comment: Ok, I will spend some time on that later.

Comment: No, we don´t. But we should.

Comment: I have updated it and removed the excess thoughts. Please take a moment to reconsider this.

Comment: I still found it too wordy for my personal liking. I majorly edited the question. If you agree on the rephrasing still carrying your essential question and not rolling back my edit, I will favor a reopening.

Comment: I am happy with the changes. I don't see anywhere I can accept the changes officially. But I do accept them.

Comment: This question has been quite extensively revised so I am reopening it for another go...